# Editing files gives permission errors

Tags: server, permissions, apache2

I have a site running on a ubuntu server and it was working fine before in terms of file permissions.
when we tried to edit files in `/var/www/html/app/Reports`, it gave  `Permission denied error` then I accidently ran this command  `sudo chown -R root:xdsluser /`
which changed owner of all files. and I instantly stopped command to run, by pressing `ctrl+c` so I don't know exactly how much files and folders are effected. Now site is giving 500 internal server error. And when I try to set permission of folders with `sudo`
it gives this error

```
sudo: /usr/bin/sudo must be owned by uid 0 and have the setuid bit set
```

OS version used

NAME="Ubuntu"

VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"

How can we set the permission now.

Comment: Firstly your system is behind on upgrades/security-fixes (a fully upgraded 20.04 or *focal* system will report as 20.04.4 and not 20.04.3), but the easiest fix is to restore your files from backups as you need to reverse the command you executed.  Your other alternative is a script that copies the permissions from your backups to your production server, as many tools won't work until you've restored settings (`sudo` won't as any error is treated as an EOF meaning data past that point is ignored; if the file has wrong settings nothing is read.you've discovered issues with `apache` etc)

Comment: You have stirred your system with a `root` stick. "Accidentally"? There are over a dozen different (UID, GID, permissions) combinations on several tens of files that must be changed back, precisely, before your system will "work" again. Given your skill level (you have 29 character "accidents"), you should probably just reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok, guys. i  think reinstalling is the only option.